# Why can't x be substituted

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have two expressions with substitution:

```
(+ x 1) [x -> 2]
```

the result is:

```
(+ 2 1)
```

Why `x` here can be substitute? It is not a function.

The second:

```
(λ x. + x 1) [x -> 2]
```

Why meta variable `x` can not be substitute it?

I've got the source from

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg0UgCg7tZQ

The time around `01:07:56`.

Comment: Please use the `lambda-calculus` tag rather than the `haskell` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` in `(λ x. + x 1)` is a *bound variable*. It does not exist outside the lambda. If you substituted `x -> 2`, you get `(λ 2. + 2 1)` - and `λ 2` is nonsense, since `2` is not a variable.

In `(+ x 1)`, `x` is a *free variable*, which we can define. If we know that `x` is `2`, we can substitute it, and get `(+ 2 1)`.

Comment: Also `(λ x . f(x)) = (λ y . f(y))` for `y` fresh name, hence given a substitution `s` you'd expect to have `(λ x . f(x))s = (λ y . f(y))s` too, which wouldn't be true if it worked like the OP thinks.

Comment: What is the difference between beta reduction and substitution. For me seems to be the same, but it is not.

Comment: Beta-reduction is the substitution of the lambda parameter within the lambda body with a given value (which is said to "evaluate" the lambda). E.g. given a lambda `(λ x. + x 1)` and a parameter value `2`, the lambda body is `(+ x 1)`, and so the associated beta-reduction is `(+ x 1)[x -> 2]`, which produces `(+ 2 1)`. The key point to keep in mind is that lambda body is not the same as the lambda. Beta-reduction is the only process that can get rid of the lambda "wrapper" and release the body inside.

Comment: So `(λ x. + x 1) 2` is an other syntax for `(+ x 1)[x -> 2]`? It is save to say  `(λ x. + x 1) 2 = (+ x 1)[x -> 2]`?

Comment: In an way, yes; kind of like "open mouth, put food in mouth, close mouth, chew, swallow" is another syntax for "stop being hungry". Function application is generally *what* you want to do; beta-reduction is the formal description of *how* it works. Or, in another sense, `(λ x. + x 1) 2 = (+ x 1)[x -> 2]` is as true as `4 + 2 = 5 + 1` - both sides evaluate to the same value (and in fact for the same reason: the way addition is defined for positive integers, a recipe for addition if you will, is `x + 0 = x; x + succ(y) = succ(x) + y`)

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation.

Comment: While you will never add numbers using this recipe, it is important because it forms the foundation of mathematics. Similarly, you don't normally need to  worry about beta-reduction, unless you want to figure out how lambda-calculus works *in theory*. In practice, in most cases, you just care about `f(x)`, or `4 + 2`, calculating what you want correctly.

Comment: This formula `x [t/x] = t` means `t` will be replace through `x`, that because they are equal. But `y [t/x] = y    (if y ≠ x)`, `t` could not be replace through `x,` because there is no `t` only `y`. What does `(if y ≠ x)` it mean?